# New Beta Theme Launched

Tags: discussion, design

Your site looks a bit different today. Yes, we are getting rid of the 'Sketchy' look and replacing it with a more-polished and finished design for sites in beta.

You can read more about the redesign of our Beta theme on our [blog entry](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/the-new-stack-exchange-beta-theme-2/).

Please note: This will not affect your "graduation" status in any way. When your site is due for graduation, it will get its final(real) site design and branding.

If you're still seeing the old favicon, please do a hard browser refresh. (Although sometimes it may take Chrome a while to load the new image).

If you see any CSS or styling issues, please report it **[in this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126185/new-stack-exchange-beta-theme)** I created on Meta Stack Overflow. It will be easier for me to track all the bug reports there.

Comment: Very professional look, good job SO team!

Comment: Not that we'll be graduating anytime soon! Regardless, the new design is great :]

Comment: Thought I hit the wrong site the first time I loaded the new look!

Comment: Is there any way to preview the final theme?